# I am using php sdk to post on facebook but the page is not loading

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I am using the following code to post on facebook from my page but the lonin page is not loading

you can see the page
[When I click on the following link the facebook required page is not loading](http://www.mrprofessional.se/ziaullah/)

The code is look like that

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '198516340340394',
  'secret' => 'f11117b96e0996ecbf7d7f4919c0cf70',
  'cookie' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_profile = null;
if ($user) {

try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', array(
    'message' => 'I want to display this message on my wall'
));
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }

}

if ($user_profile) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  echo '<a href = "$logoutUrl">Logout</a>';
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'publish_stream, read_friendlists',
  ));
  echo '<a href = "$loginUrl">Login</a>';
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PHP SDK</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Please help me in this case and please give me the detail answer, and be with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems with what you're doing here.

First it's always best to have valid markup ie doctype and html tags your page is missing. but more importantly... this

```
echo '<a href = "$loginUrl">Login</a>';
```

is wrong. the markup is just as it looks I think you're expecting a link. Change it to

```
echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login</a>;
```

and try again. the reason is php does not recognize variables in a single quoted string.